# slash vs. back slash in folder path and file path

Tags: python

HI am confused when using slash or back slash when referencing folder path and filer path. It seems to me that folder path uses `\` or file path under folder path uses `/`.

```
files=np.sort(glob('../export_result/*.csv'))
for f in files:
    print(f)
```

For example, here is output of a filename:

`../export_result\StressNodes_JLFUTop-Job_Dayfr3_to255_72A_4Part_UnDrainSide_DrainTop_NodeStress.csv`

I am confused. Is it possible to let them use consistent same either `/` or `\` ?

Comment: Where did that string come from?

Comment: files=np.sort(glob('../export_result/*.csv'))  for f in files: print(f)

Comment: I've added that to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Forward slash and backslash are just separators for separating directories and files in a path. Different systems might use different separators.
In Windows, the backslash is used as a separator:

```
C:\my_folder\myfile.txt
```

In Mac and Unix/Linux, the slash is used:

```
/home/david/my_folder/my_file.txt
```

For better and complete understanding, I suggest that you read this page:
[Python 3 Quick Tip: The easy way to deal with file paths on Windows, Mac and Linux](https://medium.com/@ageitgey/python-3-quick-tip-the-easy-way-to-deal-with-file-paths-on-windows-mac-and-linux-11a072b58d5f)

Comment: This is true, but the backslash also functions as an escape character in strings.  `'C:\my_folder\myfile.txt'` is ok, but `'C:\Users\foo'` will result in a `SyntaxError`, because Python interprets `'\U...'` as denoting the start of a unicode escape sequence in a string.

Comment: Thanks Esmaeil. I am using windows and whey the output in cases have both / and \. That is why I am confusing. Thanks